# error:Syntax Error:ESLint(syntax-parse):unexpected identifier javascript

Tags: javascript, sapui5

```
Download: function(oEvent) {
    var sUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZDEMO_GW_SRV_SRV/SalesOrderSet?$format=xlsx";
    var encodeUrl = encodeURI(sUrl);
    sap.m.URLHelper.redirect(encodeUrl, true);
}
```

I am writing this code in SAPUI5 cloud services but throwing the following error on the first line:

> error:Syntax Error:ESLint(syntax-parse):unexpected identifier
>   javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append a comma after the closing bracket of onInit.

```
onInit: function() {
},

Download : function() {
}
```

Beside that Download is a very bad name for a function.